# How do I upload files to a domain through C# winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have my own domain. I want to use it as a storage for my desktop application. I have made an application that creates a text file. Now I want to store it on my domain so that I can access it globally and by access globally I mean that I create another form that searches and displays all the text files. Even if I run my project in another pc i should not have to change anything and it keeps on working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have any FTP?For uploading a file we have many way that one of them is using FTP.
For example this code is from MSDN that using FTP:

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://www.contoso.com/test.htm");
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

    // This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential ("anonymous","janeDoe@contoso.com");

    // Copy the contents of the file to the request stream.
    StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader("testfile.txt");
    byte [] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
    sourceStream.Close();
    request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

    Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
    requestStream.Close();

    FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    Console.WriteLine("Upload File Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);

    response.Close();
    }
```

Comment: I just bought a domain from Websouls. 33 dollars an year. It gave me webspace too. Can I convert it to FTP? or is there any other method.

Comment: You should buy host and active the Ftp.